# does "public intelligence" means "intelligence service"?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language

does "public intelligence" means "intelligence service"?

If anything could annihilate Spiritualism, its present estimation by the
English public, its treatment by the Press and the courts of law, its
attempted suppression by all the powers of **public intelligence**, its hatred
by the heroes of the pulpits of all churches and creeds, the simple
acceptance of even the public folly and wickedness attributed to it by the
Press, its own internal divisions—in a word, its pre-eminent unpopularity
would put it out of existence.

source:http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html _ hos by acd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. While ‘public intelligence’ can often refer to intelligence agencies, in this case it refers to ‘common knowledge’, or ‘collective intelligence’; things ‘everybody knows’, regardless of whether they’re true or everybody really *knows* them and understands them.

So the text is saying that ‘common knowledge’ says that spiritualism is not correct, and tries to suppress it, and is a contributing part of its unpopularity, along with

> its present estimation by the English public, its treatment by the Press and the courts of law ... its hatred by the heroes of the pulpits of all churches and creeds, the simple acceptance of even the public folly and wickedness attributed to it by the Press, its own internal divisions